# Como quitar las " y espacion en mi tabla Jquery javascript (a href Generic Handler)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esto:

```
table.append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'><td name='id'>" + "<a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id='" + Data[i].id  +  " target='_blank'>"  + Data[i].id + "</a></td>"
```

y me envía como respuesta:

```
<a href="http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id=" 8744="" target="_blank">8744</a>
```

Necesito quitar la comilla doble `"` entre `?id=" 8744` y el `+""` entre el target, osea salga así:

```
<a href="http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id= 8744 target="_blank">8744</a>
```

alguien podría ayudarme? gracias.

Comment: El problema debería ser una simple comilla adicional después de id= :`table.append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'><td name='id'><a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id=" + Data[i].id  +  "  target='_blank'>"  + Data[i].id + "</a></td>");`

Comment: gracias Shaz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto

```
..."<a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id= " + Data[i].id  +  "' target='_blank'>"  + Data[i].id + "</a></td>"
```

he modificado la respuesta, creo que la falla estaba en que colocas la comilla(**'**) antes del valor del id, esto tendría que funcionar.

Comment: me da como resultado :<a href="http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id= "12725" target="_blank">12725</a> necesto quitar los "12725" nada mas falta eso

Comment: actualice la respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: Funciono gracias por tu ayuda y  tu tiempo !!!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto

```
table.append("<tr id=\"row_" + i.toString() + "\"><td name=\"id\">" + "<a href=\"http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id=\"" + Data[i].id.toString()  +  " target=\"_blank\">"  + Data[i].id.toString() + "</a></td>");
```

Comment: Gracias, quedo solucionado con la respuesta de Alan Patiño, gracias por tu tiempo